# Where to store TwiML (XML) file for Twilio in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have the following TwiML code that needs to be saved in my rails app. I then need to get the public facing url for that xml so that I can input it in the Twilio UI.

```
<Response>
<Sms>
Thanks for the message. Reply HELP for help.Reply STOP to unsubscribe.Msg&Data rates may apply.
</Sms>
</Response>
```

So, a SMS message goes out, then the person who received it responds. They should hit a URL that sends the above response back to their phone.

What is the proper way to store that XML (TWimL) in rails? Where should it live, what extension should it have (I assume .xml), and how would I access the public URL for that file?

Comment: Twilio employee here. You can definitely use a 3rd party service like Twimlbin, but you might want to provide the TwiML directly from your Rails app. I just published a blog post on how to do this, hope you find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026898/where-to-store-twiml-xml-file-for-twilio-in-rails-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just use [Twimlbin](http://twimlbin.com/) for this.

You can add your code there and it'll spit out a URL for you to add to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I just saved a .xml file in my assets/xml directory and that works fine. But this is something new to me, so I'll check it out.